# Why is my timer directive isn't working to update the View?

Tags: angularjs

im playing around with directives.

This is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/z3IBEEbw8ebVkyUFxLix?p=preview

Why isn't working? I'm trying to update the DOM from the directive.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Looks like I can't see the scope controller vars from the link function in the directive.

EDITED:

Finally made it, the code is above but you can still see it http://plnkr.co/edit/z3IBEEbw8ebVkyUFxLix?p=preview  (Is the same URL)

Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's a timer directive, where you simply do in the view <timer interval="1000">{{hour}}, {{minutes}}, {{seconds}}</timer>   those vars should be updated from the directive every 1 second by using the $interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your timer results visible on the parent, you'll want to two way data binding (the `@` is one way binding):

```
hour: "=",
minutes: "=",
seconds: "="
```

And you need to pass your scope variables in as attributes (for example `minutes="minutes"` using the `=`).  As an aside you would use `minutes="{{minutes}}"` if you stuck with one way `@` binding.

Using `=` your `timer` element looks like this:

```
<timer interval="1000" minutes="minutes" hours="hours" seconds="seconds">{{hour}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes and {{seconds}} seconds</timer>
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEKiCLDg2tkfsaIZ10xG)

Comment: oh cool, i decided to do another method too :) came up with this idea of removing the transclude, and doing everything on the link, so it would return the template with the variables, now i don't know how to pull the vars from the link function in the directive, any ideas? :) otherwise i will see yours but since im learning...

Comment: FYI, i can't see your plunker, don't know why

Comment: Updated the plunker- it should work now.  Something really odd was happening with the last one.

Comment: When you say pull the vars from the link function, do you mean how to have the controller (MainCtrl) see them?  Or?

Comment: No, see my little current template? well, i would like to update THAT template with vars i update in the link function inside the directive. The new template would be "<div>{{seconds}} seconds</div>" for example

Comment: Btw, yeah, your code looks awesome... but i would like to supply everything from the directive itself, not from any external controller or data source. Is that possible? Look at the updated plunker I'm working on http://plnkr.co/edit/z3IBEEbw8ebVkyUFxLix

Comment: Here's a plunker with that:  http://plnkr.co/edit/xEKiCLDg2tkfsaIZ10xG  You just need to either not transclude, or move the transclusion to not overlay your template values

Comment: Exactly, i realised that removing the transclusion would make the deal, i'm still trying to open the plunker you gave me, don't know why it takes like 5 minutes to open each of them... weird. Let me check it out :)

Comment: lol fixed it before looking at the code you've provided xD was easy :) just set the scope vars inside the scope in link function and used them with the bindings in the template. This is the final version http://plnkr.co/edit/z3IBEEbw8ebVkyUFxLix?p=preview thanks for your help! FYI, your plunker gives Internal Server Error from Plunker, don't know wtf is wrong with this service

Comment: I wonder if something is happening with plunker- it's acting odd right now.  Glad you've got a good solution.